# How do I add an Error Handling Message when the .csv file is not in the directory using Python?

Tags: python, csv, error-handling

Seeking for your assistance again on how I can add an Error Handling Message when the .csv file is not in the directory. How do I this? Sorry, still learning stuff in Python but thank you very much in advance.

Full code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import tkinter
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()

directory = 'C:/Path1'
ext = ('.csv')

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
f = os.path.join(directory, filename)

if f.endswith(ext):

    head_tail = os.path.split(f)
    head_tail1 = 'C:/Path2'
    k =head_tail[1]
    r=k.split(".")[0]

    p=head_tail1 + "/" + r + " - .csv"
    mydata = pd.read_csv(f, engine='python')

    # to pull columns and values
    new = mydata[["A","B","C","D"]]
    new = new.rename(columns={'D': 'F'})
    new['F'] = 1
    print(new.columns)
    new["B"] = (pd.to_datetime(new["B"], format="%d-%b", errors="coerce").dt.strftime("%#m-%#d").fillna(new["B"]))
    new.to_csv(p ,index=False)

    #to merge columns and values
    merge_columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
    merged_col = ''.join(merge_columns).replace('ABC', 'G')
    new[merged_col] = new[merge_columns].astype(str).apply(lambda x: '.'.join(x), axis=1)
    new.drop(merge_columns, axis=1, inplace=True)
    new = new.groupby(merged_col).count().reset_index()
    new.to_csv(p, index=False)

    messagebox.showinfo("Done.")


    os.chdir("C:/Path2")

    for file in os.listdir():
        if file.endswith(".xlsx"):
    if os.path.exists("Master.xlsx"):
        os.rename("Master.xlsx", "Old_Master.xlsx")
    os.rename(file, "Master.xlsx")
```

I tried adding this on the script but it is still doing its function even if the file is not in the directory.

```
    import os
    import pandas as pd
    import openpyxl
    import tkinter
    from tkinter import messagebox

    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    directory = 'C:/Path1'
    ext = ('.csv')

    for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    f = os.path.join(directory, filename)

    if f.endswith(ext):

    #added line############### 
    if os.path.isfile(directory):
        print("File does exist at this time")
    else:
        print("No such file exists at this time")

    head_tail = os.path.split(f)
    head_tail1 = 'C:/Path2'
    k =head_tail[1]
    r=k.split(".")[0]

    p=head_tail1 + "/" + r + " - .csv"
    mydata = pd.read_csv(f, engine='python')
```

Comment: @AbirbhavG, the link you provided gave me an idea. It is working when the file is in the directory, however it doesn't work when the file is not in the directory. I tried inserting this         if os.path.isfile(f):
            print("Good")
        else:
            print("Bad")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is easier than what you doing:

```
import os

file_found = False

for file in os.listdir("C:/Folder"):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        file_found = True
        break

if file_found:
    print("There's .csv file in C:/Folder.")
else:
    print("Error! There's no .csv file in C:/Folder.")
```